# Tweepy install Red Hat

Tags: python-2.7, redhat, tweepy

Hi im newbie un tweepy i need install this component in my RedHat but i 'cant

Here the message:

```
ec2-user@ip-172-30-0-62 opitrends]$ sudo pip install tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",        line 3020, in <module>
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 616, in _build_master
return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 629, in _build_from_requirements
dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==6.1.1
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-0-62 opitrends]$
```

Someone help me??

Thanks
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell what's going on, but that's an older version of pip and that might be the problem. Try upgrading pip:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then retry.